# Why can't these two scripts co-exist?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The first code is supposed to return a static date in Column H if I fill out a checkbox in Column G.

The second code is supposed to return a static date whenever I write "_now" in any cell.

The problem is that whenever I add the second code, the first code stops working. If I remove the second code and save, the first one works again. Does anyone have an idea why both of these codes cannot co-exist and how I can solve this?

```
function onEdit() {
   var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   if( s.getName() == "Database" ) { //checks that we're on the "Database" sheet
      var r = s.getActiveCell();
      if( r.getColumn() == 7 ) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column G
         var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
         if( nextCell.getValue() === '') //checks if the adjacent cell is empty or not?
             nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}

function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getValue() == "_now" ) {
    e.range.setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Comment: We can not copy and paste from an image

Comment: There is no function overloading in JavaScript. You have two functions named the same thing. When you add the second one, it overrides the first. Hence why two functions named the same thing can not co-exist. So you need to combine both functions together.

Comment: Thank you @epascarello . The overloading was the problem so I changed the name of the second onEdit(e) to onEdit2(e) and added another trigger for that one. That seems to have worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = e.range.getSheet();
  if (s.getName() == "Database") {
    var e.range = s.getActiveCell();
    if (e.range.getColumn() == 7) { 
      var nextCell = e.range.offset(0, 1);
      if (nextCell.getValue() == '') 
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }

  if (e.range.getValue() == "_now") {
    e.range.setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```